# Where do services that compute travel time get traffic data?

Tags: routing, traffic, real-time

Recently, I have been studying routing services that calculate travel time and distance. And I had a question, where do these services get traffic data from. I found a lot of information about Google. And if Google can take this information from applications, then where do other services get the data from? Perhaps they use cellular communications or mobile operators or combine some other data.

Comment: Cell phones/towers with gps on. 'bucketing and cleaning/smoothing raw data' https://patents.google.com/patent/US20100286899?oq=maps+traffic+inassignee:google

Answer (score 1):

In the Distancematrix.ai company we gather data from public traffic data sources. Our product predicts travel time based on statistics on congestion in different regions, and, in terms of accuracy, it is very close to the Google Distance Matrix API. Here you can read about the API [https://distancematrix.ai/product](https://distancematrix.ai/product?utm_source=gis&utm_medium=answer&utm_campaign=dev_3)

As for other companies, they use many such sources of traffic data as road sensors, cellular communications, traffic data from people using maps apps on their smartphones, etc. And each company uses those data sources that are accessible and beneficial to it.